# Scrapy: Multiple spiders into a single JSON file

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm trying to run a scrapy project that takes multiple spiders and feeds the results into a single JSON file. I'm using [CrawlerRunner](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process/%22Crawler%20Runner%22) from the Scrapy Docs in a file called **base.py** -

```
import scrapy
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from my_project.spiders.spider1 import Spider1Spider
from my_project.spiders.spider2 import Spider2Spider

settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(Spider1Spider)
    yield runner.crawl(Spider2Spider)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
```

And in **settings.py** I have

```
FEED_FORMAT = 'json'
FEED_URI = 'filename.json'
```

But when I run **base.py** the JSON file has square brackets - **][** - betweeen the results of spider1 & spider2 making it an invalid JSON file.

Using the Scrapy example, **spider1.py**

```
import scrapy

class Spider1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first()
            }
```

and **spider2.py**

```
import scrapy

class Spider2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider2'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first()
            }
```

gives results:

```
[
{"text": "\u201cThe world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.\u201d"},
{"text": "\u201cIt is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.\u201d"}
][
{"author": "Marilyn Monroe"},
{"author": "J.K. Rowling"}
]
```

Where as the expecting result would be

```
[
{"text": "\u201cThe world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.\u201d"},
{"text": "\u201cIt is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.\u201d"},
{"author": "Marilyn Monroe"},
{"author": "J.K. Rowling"}
]
```

What am I missing? Do I need an Item Pipeline to get results from multiple spiders into a single, valid JSON file?

**EDIT**

This is the pipeline I've played with but at the moment it only yields half the results, the `author` results only

```
import json

class TestPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('file_name.json', 'wb')
        self.file.write("[")

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.write("]")
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(
            dict(item),
            sort_keys=True,
            indent=4,
            separators=(',', ': ')
        ) + ",\n"

        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I think you may need to implement a custom pipeline for that. As an alternative, I would recommend using `jsonlines` format.

Comment: thanks @stasdeep , I'm playing around with that now. I've added an example of the pipeline as an edit above. Any ideas why it's only yielding half the results?

Comment: This pipeline is created for each spider. So when you have 2 spiders, your `Spider1` is launched, it writes to `filename.json` and saves; then `Spider2` is launched and it **rewrites** the `filename.json`.

Comment: Thanks @stasdeep ! That makes sense! If I'm trying to get the results from multiple spiders into one JSON file, any ideas how I could do that?
JSON Lines would work, and I could then convert it to JSON, but is there a workflow that you are aware of that would work? Scrapy Middleware or a different Pipeline?

Comment: Why not do that in `crawl` function that you already have?

Comment: With the current `crawl` function I can't get a valid JSON file when multiple spiders are fed into it (which is the goal). I've been playing around with it but I can't figure it out. The `crawl` function is working well but the results are broken - extraneous **]** square brackets are added, so I have to manually find them and remove them to use the data

Comment: Why not export into 2 different files (like `first.json` and `second.json`) and then merge them in `crawl` function into `filename.json`?

Comment: oh! good idea. I'll give that a try. I'd already tried using jquery's .extend() method but it wasn't great. Merging in `crawl` would be much cleaner. Cheers!